# Blender game normal mapping

Tags: game-engine, node-editor, normals

I have a ground tile for which I use a normal map, it reacts good when facing light, but looking in the Sun lamp direction kills the lightning. I'm using nodes, have a look at the pictures.
Can somebody tell me what's wrong with my setup ?
(connecting the texture normal output straight to the material gives the same result)

[image: facing light] 
[image: following light direction]

Comment: Normal mapping is a real pain in the node editor. In fact, it's an open bug. https://developer.blender.org/T41829
I seem to recall a few months ago someone mentioned made a new node to fix this, but I haven't seen it in official builds yet.

Comment: Blender is surprising sometimes... Thanks for the link it might help.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a Normal Map node in between the Texture node and the Material node?

Comment: Is there a reason I should do so ? I think the matter has been clarified. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal mapping is a real pain in the node editor. In fact, it's an [open bug](http://developer.blender.org/T41829).  I seem to recall a few months ago someone mentioned/made a new node to fix this, but I haven't seen it in official builds yet.

The way around it I sometimes use (it's computationally expensive and a pain to set up), is to create a material for each normal map. Then you can take the normal output from the material and mix that together:
[image: A solution]
Sorry for not mentioning this in my comment earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You could try advanced material node. This can be  found under the input menu. Otherwise you could just add the normal map in the texture panel and enable normal map at the bottom.